# Spring Data JPA Pagination without count query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

According to Spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters returning with `List` should not issue count query.

But with my spring it goes kinda strange.

When running page request with page `1` it works without count query which i suppose is right.

[image: Requested with page 1]

But when I invoke repository with page `2`(or above) suddenly it does a count query after select query which I didn't expect.

[image: Requested with page 2 or above]

Is there any way that I could make count query **not issued** with using Pageable?

Repository and service code for what i did.

```java
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {
  // Slice was also tested and did issue count query from page 2
  List<Article> findAll(Pageable pageable);
} 

@Service
public class ArticleService {
  private final ArticleRepository articleRepository;

  @Autowired
  public ArticleService(
      ArticleRepository articleRepository) {
    this.articleRepository = articleRepository;
  }

  public List<Article> getArticles(int page) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, 50, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
    return articleRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this applies to Slice and List (in the repository). Did you try Slice ? https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/pagination-sorting-example/

Comment: @PeterMmm Tried slice and still issuing count query from page 2

Comment: fyi, for simplicity you should be able to autowire ArticleRepository with just: @AutoWired private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

Comment: This is an interesting question. Based on the logs, the count query appears to issued when I try this, too (even for page 1). Makes me question the Spring documentation ("... the additional count query that would have been necessary is not issued").

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extend CrudRepository, then you will be able to define method with [Slice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) in your repository:

```java
Slice<Article> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

I think that other option is change the super interface to `PagingAndSortingRepository`. It can solve the use of `List` on the return.

```java
interface ArticleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Article, Long> {
    List<Article> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Changing to Slice is working as same as above. Page 1 will wont issue count query but starting from page 2 it issues count query.
For changing super interface to `PagingAndSortingRepository` I can't override findAll since return type is different.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? What version?

Comment: Yep using spring boot v2.6.1 (Also tested with 2.5.x but seems working same)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can compose PagingAndSortingRepository and CrudRepository as they both are interfaces or use JpaRepository instead.
2. you can write your own count query by setting it into @Query annotation.

in source code for `public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)` there is `totalSupplier` which executes count query to get total number.

```java
if (content.size() != 0 && pageable.getPageSize() > content.size()) {
    return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, pageable.getOffset() + content.size());
}
return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, totalSupplier.getAsLong());
```

So you cannot avoid it with default repository method. Specify you own jpa method or declare query annotation under `PagingAndSortingRepository` class.